# How do you access the Servlet Context (on the server) when using GWT Request Factory?

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I need access to the ServletContext object that is usually available in servlets so that I can call methods like:

```
String fullPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("images/file.jpg");
```

I'm sure there is something built-in, I just need to figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
String fullPath = RequestFactoryServlet.getThreadLocalServletContext().getRealPath("images/file.jpg");
```